# Separate Int from String on file input

Tags: java

i was wondering if anyone could help me with a little problem in Java:
I have a file with some equations like:

```
Z=1X1+3X2
-1X1+5X2<=2
1X1-1X2<=56
```

and so on..

and i wanted to read this file and separate the values 1 and 3 (of Z=1X1+3X2) in one string and -1,5,2,1,-1,56 in another.

Comment: What code do you have so far, and what specific problems are you having with it?

Comment: Learn how to use Regular Expressions, they can do this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty solving it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Sorry if i couldnt give more details because all i have is that could help is the input file (shown above) the code itself to reach my result is just scratcy attemps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your needs, it looks like something that could be solved using regex or string splitting by a regex number pattern then filtering out what you need.

Example of doing the first line for matching 1 and 3

```
    String s = "Z=1X1+3X2";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([13])");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }
```

or via split

```
String[] split = s.split("\\D");
// for every item in array, if 1 or 3 do something with it..
```

Comment: I had tryied that option (the split one) but i get blank spaces in some of the array positions, and i will need this array to convert the values to int and use them.

Comment: My example was just an overview on how to get at the data, you still need to parse and process according to the format you need. Java has various utility methods for that `Integer.parseInt`, just ignore empties.

Comment: Omg i completely forgot about `Integer.parseInt` xD. Thanks for the help :D

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string using regular expression to separate the digits.

```
String[] split = s.split("\\D");
```